# Worklight Server V6.0: Issue with log in after enabling application center security

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

When I enable an ldapregistry in the Liberty profile and configure the appcentre to make use of "user S", I get the following error when logging in:

```
com.ibm.ws.security.registry.RegistryException: com.ibm.websphere.wim.model.Entity cannot be cast to com.ibm.websphere.wim.model.Group
at com.ibm.ws.wim.registry.WIMUserRegistry.getUniqueGroupIdsForUser(WIMUserRegistry.java:378)
at com.ibm.ws.security.credentials.wscred.internal.WSCredentialProvider.getUniqueGroupAccessIds(WSCredentialProvider.java:219)
at com.ibm.ws.security.credentials.wscred.internal.WSCredentialProvider.createUserWSCredential(WSCredentialProvider.java:164)
at com.ibm.ws.security.credentials.wscred.internal.WSCredentialProvider.setCredential(WSCredentialProvider.java:138)
at com.ibm.ws.security.credentials.wscred.internal.WSCredentialProvider.setCredential(WSCredentialProvider.java:96)
at com.ibm.ws.security.credentials.internal.CredentialsServiceImpl.setCredentials(CredentialsServiceImpl.java:57)
```

-Worklight Server V6.0 (WAS Liberty V8.5.5)

Not sure if this is a Worklight or Liberty issue, has anyone else seen this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AppCenter authentication mechanism is completely based on the Liberty Profile J2EE security feature. So when you log in AppCenter only the application server security layer is involved. Viewing the exception it looks like the lDAPRegistry definition in server.xml is not correct. It looks like the search for a user returns a group. 
So you have to check the ldapRegistry properties especially userFilter, groupFilter, groupIdMap, userIdMap.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Bruno. After some more investigation, including removing Worklight from the picture, we did find that there is some LDAP config change between Liberty 8.5 and 8.5.5 that was causing the problem. A change to our filter seems to have fixed the problem, although as of yet do not know why the change is required.